# Where are the docs (docx, xls etc) are physically store when using onlyoffice?

Tags: onlyoffice

I assume it's not on 'document-server'? Is it true that all documents are being stored as database entities in a db?

Answer (score 0):

Some information is stored in the db but the documentserver also contains information such as change history, changes and current output under `documentserver/server/App_data`